# Reading in information into separate arrays

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I've been having some difficulties reading in information from a file into separate arrays. An example of the information in the file is:

```
14 Barack Obama:United States  
17 David Cameron:United Kingdom  
27 Vladimir Putin:Russian Federation  
19 Angela Merkel:Germany
```

While I can separate the integers into an array, I am having trouble creating an array for the names and an array for the countries. This is my code thus far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class leadRank {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int size;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
    size = input.nextInt();
    int[] rank = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < rank.length; i++) {
        rank[i] = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
    }
    String[] name = new String[size]; 
    for (int i = 0; i <name.length; i++) { 
        artist[i] =
```

I think that I would have to read in the line as a string and use indexOf to find the colon in order to start a new array but I'm unsure as to how to execute that.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you need to read the file line by line, split on whitespace and extract integer and then split on colon and make corresponding array?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to solve your problem in my ways. It was just for a time pass. Hopes this may helps you.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class leadRank {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int size;
    File file = new File("names.txt");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    String s;

    LineNumberReader  lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(file));
    lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    size = lnr.getLineNumber()+1;
    lnr.close();

    int[] rank = new int[size];
    String[] name = new String[size];
    String[] country = new String[size];

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        int i=0;
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String temp = s;
            if(temp.contains(":")){
                String[] splitres = temp.split(":");
                String sub = splitres[0];

                rank[i] = Integer.parseInt(sub.substring(0,sub.indexOf(" "))); // Adding rank to array rank[]
                name[i] = sub.substring(sub.indexOf(" "), sub.length()-1);  // Adding name to array name[]
                country[i] = splitres[1]; // Adding the conutries to array country[]

            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more efficient because it goes through the file only once.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    // create an array list because the size of the array is still not know
    ArrayList<Integer> ranks = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> countries = new ArrayList<String>();

    // read the input file
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));

    // read each line
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String wholeLine = input.nextLine();

        // get the index of the first space
        int spaceIndex = wholeLine.indexOf(" ");

        // parse the rank
        int rank;
        try {
            rank = Integer.parseInt(wholeLine.substring(0, spaceIndex));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            rank = -1;
        }

        // parse the name & country
        String[] tokens = wholeLine.substring(spaceIndex + 1).split(":");
        String name = tokens[0];
        String country = tokens[1];

        // add to the arrays
        ranks.add(rank);
        names.add(name);
        countries.add(country);
    }

    // get your name and country arrays if needed
    String[] nameArr = names.toArray(new String[]{});
    String[] countryArr = countries.toArray(new String[]{});

    // the rank array has to be created manually
    int[] rankArr = new int[ranks.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < ranks.size(); i++) {
        rankArr[i] = ranks.get(i).intValue();
    }
}
```